# Gerrit: Merged, Outdated

Tags: git, gerrit

I am observing status of one of the Gerrit dependencies for my commit on `/refs/for/master` as: `(MERGED) [OUTDATED]`. What does it mean?

I am using Gerrit Code Review (2.6.1-117-g04facf7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say change B depends on change A

In the view for change B you see `(MERGED) [OUTDATED]`

`(MERGED)` 
This means that the change A (on which B depends) was merged into the master branch. Which is fine, no problems here.

`[OUTDATED]` This means that change A is outdated in change B's history. A common cause for this is that a new patchset was created for change A while B still depends on the old patchset. A rebase is needed to make change B depend on the newest changes in change A.

These 'statuses' do not always appear together. It's perfectly valid to have only one of them, or neither, or in your case, both. It all depends on the state of the dependency and the relation of the two changes.

Comment: Tim, would you mind swapping A and B in your explanation? I think it's easier to understand if B follows A :-)